# Prove that if $n\neq 2 \pmod 4$ then there exists a primitive Pythagorean triple $(x,y,z)$ in which $x$ or $y$ equals $n$

Tags: congruences, pythagorean-triples, congruence-relations

If $n\neq2\mod 4$, then there are three possibilities:

$n\equiv0\pmod 4, n\equiv1\pmod 4$, and $n\equiv3\pmod 4.$

Can I have some help after this point? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at a list of primitive pythagorean triples (there are many on line) you should be able to form some conjectures. There's also a well known formula for all primitive pythagorean triples you can look up and use.

Comment: That doesn't fit with your question at all

Comment: But it's obvious. If $n\ncong 2\ \ (\text{mod}4)$ then $n\equiv 0\ \ \text{or}\ \ n\equiv 1\ \ \text{or}\ \ n\equiv 3\ \ \ (\text{mod}4).$

Answer (score 0):

From $x^2+y^2=z^2$ we have
$$x^2=(z-y)(z+y)$$
so your goal is to find two factors $a<b$ such that $ab=x^2$, $a=z-y$, $b=z+y$. The system
$$\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}z-y=a\\z+y=b\end{matrix}\right.$$
has an integer solution if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. What happens for $x=1$?

Answer (score 0):

since n is not of the form 4n+2, it can be written as the difference of 2 squares,
say $$n = a^2 - b^2$$
we can now produce $$m = 2ab$$
so now, $$m^2 + n^2 = (a^2 + b^2)^2$$, which is a primitive pythagorean triple.